# LESS (Leaner CSS) conflicts with Google Analytics and Webmaster Tools

Tags: css, less

I have a Joomla website that uses  LESS (Leaner-CSS) as its stylesheet language.

In Google Webmaster Tools, even in the very beginning where there is a thumbnail picture of all the websites I'm administrator, I'm not able to see the image preview because the styles don't load - I just get a list with the website names. And in Google Analytics the same happens, so I'm not able for example to make use of all the functions such as the On Page analytics. Is there any work around for this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share the website having the issue?

Comment: Are you using client-only LESS (literally just dropping less-1.5.0.min.js on a page and only hosting .less files) or are you precompiling (turning .less into .css beforehand) on the server side?

Comment: Yes here it is: www.birdsandcompany.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you've taken a client-only approach to LESS, which means page visitors have to compile the latest .less stylesheet on their end. Ideally, you'd want to avoid going down this path, because it *requires the client to have Javascript enabled to get styles.* From the look of it, Google's page capture tools don't run Javascript on the page, so they don't compile the stylesheet.

Try turning Javascript off in your browser and you'll see the page how Google sees it.

The solution is to precompile your .less files on the server side and serve them as .css, which nearly all browsers (even the Google Webmaster Tools crawler) can understand natively. There are lots of guides on how to do this with Node.js. It's better for performance too!